# How to get free programmatic access to citations counts for a given paper?

Tags: publications, citations, databases

What databases allow free, programmatic access to cited-by counts for papers?

- Google Scholar doesn't have an API, and they block crawling attempts.
- SCOPUS only seems to allows you to retrieve a branded, watermarked image of the number.

Comment: Do you have a specific field in mind?

Comment: @nate, yes, primarily biomedical science.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are an [R](http://www.r-project.org) user, you can use the [scholar](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scholar/) package. This package allows you to analyze data from Google Scholar and obtain citations, publication list and even perform predictions of the h-index. An example R code:

```
library(scholar)
id = "xJaxiEEAAAAJ" # Isaac Newton's id
cit=get_citation_history(id)
barplot(cit[,2],names.arg = cit[,1])
```

[image: Isaac Newton's citation history]

Answer (score 3):

I was hunting around for something like this recently to create citation count "badges" for papers. I came across [scholar.py](https://github.com/ckreibich/scholar.py.git) by Christian Kreibich. It uses BeautifulSoup to parse Google Scholar HTML output.

> - Extracts publication title, most relevant web link, PDF link, number of citations, number of online versions, link to Google Scholar's article cluster for the work, Google Scholar's cluster of all works referencing the publication, and excerpt of content.
> - Python module
> - Command-line tool prints entries in CSV format, simple plain text, or in the citation export format.

For example:

`./scholar.py -c 1 --author "Hutchison" -t -A "Avogadro"`

```
     Title Avogadro: An advanced semantic chemical editor, visualization, and analysis platform.
       URL http://www.biomedcentral.com/content/pdf/1758-2946-4-17.pdf
      Year 2012
 Citations 743
```

Answer (score 3):

Wikidata has some incomplete citation information and you can access it programmatically via XML dumps, RDF dumps, web API and the SPARQL endpoint called Wikidata Query Service.

In Scholia at https://tools.wmflabs.org/scholia/, we use Wikidata Query Service to generate citation counts and citation list, see an example for "The Alzheimer's disease-associated amyloid beta-protein is an antimicrobial peptide" here:  https://tools.wmflabs.org/scholia/work/Q21090025

If you follow the link on the page you can get to the SPARQL queries. For the SPARQL query that generate the "Citations to the work" table with citation count, the SPARQL query currently reads:

```
#defaultView:Table
# List of works that is cited by the specified work
SELECT ?citations ?publication_date ?citing_work ?citing_workLabel 
WITH {
  SELECT (MIN(?date) AS ?publication_date) (COUNT(?citing_citing_work) AS ?citations) ?citing_work 
  WHERE {
    ?citing_work wdt:P2860 wd:Q21090025 .
    OPTIONAL {
      ?citing_work wdt:P577 ?datetime .
      BIND(xsd:date(?datetime) AS ?date)
    }
    OPTIONAL { ?citing_citing_work wdt:P2860 ?citing_work }
  }
  GROUP BY ?citing_work
} AS %result
WHERE {
  INCLUDE %result
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en,da,de,es,fr,it,jp,nl,no,ru,sv,zh" . } 
} 
ORDER BY DESC(?citations) DESC(?date)
```

You can obtain the information programmatically, e.g., in Python

```
import requests

query = """
#defaultView:Table
# List of works that is cited by the specified work
SELECT ?citations ?publication_date ?citing_work ?citing_workLabel 
WITH {
  SELECT (MIN(?date) AS ?publication_date) (COUNT(?citing_citing_work) AS ?citations) ?citing_work 
  WHERE {
    ?citing_work wdt:P2860 wd:Q21090025 .
    OPTIONAL {
      ?citing_work wdt:P577 ?datetime .
      BIND(xsd:date(?datetime) AS ?date)
    }
    OPTIONAL { ?citing_citing_work wdt:P2860 ?citing_work }
  }
  GROUP BY ?citing_work
} AS %result
WHERE {
  INCLUDE %result
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en,da,de,es,fr,it,jp,nl,no,ru,sv,zh" . } 
} 
ORDER BY DESC(?citations) DESC(?date) 
"""

response = requests.get('https://query.wikidata.org/sparql',
                        params={'query': query, 'format': 'json'})
data = response.json()['results']['bindings']
format = lambda paper: paper['citations']['value'] + ' ' + paper['citing_workLabel']['value']

>>> print("\n".join([format(paper) for paper in data[:5]]))
75 The genetics of Alzheimer disease
25 Alzheimer's disease - a neurospirochetosis. Analysis of the evidence following Koch's and Hill's criteria
23 Mild cognitive impairment: pathology and mechanisms.
22 Immunotherapeutic approaches for Alzheimer's disease
18 Amyloid-β peptide: Dr. Jekyll or Mr. Hyde?
```

Comment: It doesn't have data on most researchers

Comment: In many areas, the citation information in Wikidata is very incomplete. For papers in PubMedCentral it is better, - but likely incomplete.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft Academic Search provides an API as a part of the [Cognitive Services Lab](https://labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/en-us/sign-up). Unfortunately, you cannot look up papers by DOI; you will need to manually retrieve the Microsoft Academic paper ID or use title search for lookup. But it gives you citation count as well as an estimated count for widely-cited papers. I am successfully using it to include citation counts in my CV.

Answer (score 2):

Let me add [Semantic Scholar](https://www.semanticscholar.org/) to the list.

There's both an official [REST API](https://api.semanticscholar.org/) for Paper/Author lookup and a [Python package](https://github.com/danielnsilva/semanticscholar).

Metrics include 'citations', 'influentialCitationCount', 'citationVelocity'