# How to find scientists that cited several of my papers?

Tags: publications, citations, online-resource

There are several ways to find online scientists that cited one of your papers (Google Scholar, PubMed, Web of Science, etc). Recently, however, I ran into a scenario in which I wanted to find authors that cited a specific subset of my papers. To clarify, I don't mean that these citations have to be in the same paper - they could be in different papers by the same author.

One option would be to export the citation data for each of my papers and write some script that parses and extracts the answer. Does anyone know of a simpler/online method of doing this sort of complex query?

Comment: related [question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/28978/21435) and [answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/28983/21435)

Comment: @ddiez thanks, I see there are parsers in other programming languages as well. I wasn't aware that exporting from Google Scholar is such an issue. In any case it would still be nice if there is some online tool that could do this type of stuff.

Comment: Related-but-no-duplicate: [How to search for list of papers citing both papers A and B?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/28164/how-to-search-for-list-of-papers-citing-both-papers-a-and-b)

Comment: @Bitwise unfortunately that package is still a bit limited in its capabilities and what you want to do cannot be done out of the box. Hence, I cannot post an answer :-) Hopefully in the future.

Comment: If you have so many papers/citations that this isn't trivial to do by hand... that's a good problem to have.

Comment: @NateEldredge good problem, but still a problem. Also consider the fact that in biology some papers can have hundreds of authors...

Answer (score 2):

You need to first get a database put together of all those who potentially might have cited your work, and the bibliography of their papers.  This is not trivial, esp. if you are in a field where you don't have pre-existing online citation databases for published works.

Are your works available in such a format?  If so, then just do a query which you think will capture all the related papers to your work.  If you are cited in MEDLINE, you can use the "paper like this" as well as exploded MeSH based searches.  Start with the MeSH terms assigned to your work, and spend a little time going over where those show up in the MeSH hierarchy.

Also, how are you defining a specific subset of your papers?  Is this something you know *a priori* or are you expecting that subsets fall out based on who cited your work?

If your subset is small, and/or you don't have many citing authors, this would  be quicker to just do by hand.  Just build a bibliography from those who cited you (e.g. export Google Scholar/MEDLINE entries, which will have all the authors), and you can then parse that (download them in an XML format and you can probably use XPath/XQuery to do what you need, or see of one of Zotero's report options will help).